# How to pull a certain branch from a upstream repository

Tags: github, gitpython

Assume I have a local git clone called GitPython. I'm able to commit and push using gitpython:

```
repo = Repo(D:\Dev\Gitpython)
print(repo.git.add("."))
print(repo.git.commit(m='my commit message'))
print(repo.git.push())
```

However, how can I pull from the upstream repository using gitpython?
I tried to create an remote object by using Repo.create_remote(), but it gives me an error since the remote is already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the connection already exist your should be able to pull.

```
repo = git.Repo('repo_name')
o = repo.remotes.origin
o.pull()


o = repo.remotes.origin
o.fetch('branch_name')
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur, your code works. But how do I pull a specific branch?

Comment: @PatrickYu to pull from a specific branch, use `o.pull('name-of-branch')`

Comment: @PatrickYu you can also use 'repo.remotes.origin.fetch('branch_name')'